# How to save Excel File as PDF and fit to page

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

i have a task to create function to export Excel file into PDF with requirements that all columns must fit in 1 page .

This is the code i use to convert excel file to pdf.

```
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(textBox3.Text);
xlWb.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, Path.GetDirectoryName(textBox3.Text)+ "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(textBox3.Text) + ".pdf");
```

But when i open it , it appears that the columns is separated, like if i have like 10 columns , it will split like the first 6 columns in the first page and the last 4 columns in the second page.

How to make it fit to page? it is okay if the potrait is landscape too

Comment: Did you use Microsoft Interop or a 3rd party to do your exporting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so after i do some research , this is the way to setup your page orientation , and you can fit to page

```
//setup your page orientation + fit to pages
    xlWs2.PageSetup.Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
    xlWs2.PageSetup.Zoom = false;
    xlWs2.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
    xlWs2.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = false;
//this is how to save as PDF     
xlWb2.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF,Path.GetDirectoryName(textBox3.Text) + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(textBox3.Text) + ".pdf");
```

P.S  :xlWs2 is excel.Worksheets, xlWb2 is excel.Workbooks

Comment: xlWs2.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 0;
//the type must be int, not bool

Answer (score 0):

you can use spire.xls to convert the file and the PageSetup to fit your file like that:

```
PageSetup setup = worksheet.PageSetup;
setup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
setup.FitToPagesTall = 1;
```